# How old is file?

Tags: unix

I have a shell script that will check a file is how many days old. I did `stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" "$file"` . But I want to store this into a variable and then compare current time and file created time ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `bash`, you can capture the output of commands with something like:

```
fdate=$(stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" "$file")
```

and then do whatever you will with the results:

```
echo ${fdate}
```

That's assuming the command itself works in the first place. If you are, you can ignore the text below.

---

The GNU `stat` program uses `-f` to specify you want to query the filesystem rather than a file and the other options you have don't seem to make sense in the context of your question.

Using Gnu `stat`, you can get the time since the last file update<sup>(1)</sup> as:

```
ageInSeconds=$(($(date -u +%s) - $(stat --printf "%Y" "file")))
```

The subtracts the last modification time of the file from the current time (both expressed as seconds since the epoch) to give you the age in seconds.

To turn that into days, assuming you're not overly concerned about the possible error from leap seconds (an error of, at *most,* one part in about 15.7 million, or 0.000006%), you can just divide it by 86,400:

```
ageInDays=$((($(date -u +%s) - $(stat --printf "%Y" "file")) / 86400))
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that, although `stat` purports to have a `%W` format specifier that gives the birth of the file, this doesn't always work (it returns zero). You *could* check that first if you're really interested in when the file was created rather than last updated but you may have to be prepared to accept the possibility the information is not available. I've used last modification time above since, frequently, it's used for things like detecting changes.

Comment: Thanxx for ur help @paxdiablo....how can i only store the date from it ?
And when i run 
ageInSeconds=$(($(date -u +%s) - $(stat --printf "%Y" "file")))

Comment: Thanxx for ur help @paxdiablo....how can i only store the date from it ?
And when i run 
ageInSeconds=$(($(date -u +%s) - $(stat --printf "%Y" "file")))
I got following error 
stat: illegal option -- -
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
./getTimeCreated.sh: line 16: 1452581883 - : syntax error: operand expected (error token is " ")

Comment: @Mohit, then you're not using GNU stat. You can either use the command you gave in the question (assuming it delivers what you need) or download/compile/install the GNU one for the extra power.

Comment: Thats how i did and it worked for me :
#!/bin/sh
file=/Users/mrane/Desktop/Source/Purge_work/hdfs_purge.log
 echo "$file"
 MPHR=60
 current=`date +%s`
 echo "$current"
 #fdate=$(stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" "$file")
 fdate=$(stat -f "%m" "$file")
 
 #ddate=$(stat -c %y test.txt | cut -d ' ' -f1)
 echo "$fdate"
MINUTES=$(( ($current - $fdate) / $MPHR )) 
echo "$MINUTES"
 #echo "the difference is $((current - fdate)) minutes"